# LESS css set dynamic background image with mixin

Tags: css, variables, less, mixins

I am using [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org) .

I am currently using Mixins with variables. 
 
Something like this works okay :

```
.border-radius (@radius) { border-radius: @radius; }

#header { .border-radius(4px);  }
```

This is **not** :

```
.bg-img(@img) { background-image:url(@img); }

#logo { .bg-img("../images/logo.jpg"); }
```

i have tried combinations of using ' & " in the background-image:url **('') & ("")** but then it tries to get the image as `images/@img` instead of the image name. other wise it gives me an error of 
 `Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined`

I think writing `background-image:url()` all the time is too tedious, is this possible..?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

:) got my answer!

it needs to be used like this in my case :

```
.bg-img(@img) { background-image:url("@{img}"); }

#logo { .bg-img("../images/logo.jpg"); }
```

Answer (score 12):

You can further improve on this by adding the first part of the image path to the initial mixin so you only have to write it once:

```
.bg-img(@img) { background-image:url("../images/@{img}"); }

#logo { .bg-img("logo.jpg"); }
```

A small improvement but does add a little elegance.