# LESS CSS - ID and background para

Tags: css, less

Instead of repeating this CSS in my .less file. Would anyone know how to create a LESS function for the following?

```
li  #prize-1 span {
                background: url('@{imagesUrl}/1.png') no-repeat;
                width: 874px;
                height: 188px;
            }   
li  #prize-2 span {
                background: url('@{imagesUrl}/2.png') no-repeat;
                width: 874px;
                height: 188px;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it not be something like this

```
.definition (@image: nameOfImageDefault) {
  background: url('@{imagesUrl}/@{image}') no-repeat;
  width: 874px;
  height: 188px;
}

li  #prize-1 span {
    .definition(nameOfImage);
        }   
li  #prize-2 span {
    .definition(nameOfImage);
}
```

I am not that familiar with LESS so I think this works

Edit:

I am following this example from their homepage

```
.rounded-corners (@radius: 5px) {
  border-radius: @radius;
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
  -moz-border-radius: @radius;
}

#header {
  .rounded-corners;
}
#footer {
  .rounded-corners(10px);
}
```

also which part did not work? the background image? maybe try to take in the entire image path with the name as the variable

Comment: @user1381806 can you try defining the imageUrl as in use the path and not the variable in .definition I don't have LESS installed so I can't test it. Can you post your code.

Comment: I edited my answer, source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334644/less-css-set-dynamic-background-image-with-mixin I just added {} around "image" I am sure it is something like that if not exactly that but there is a way for sure